# How to solve 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dataSet' error

Tags: c#

I have set dataset property globally in class like below, And binding gridview in pageload event.so throwing like below error
/*Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataSet*/

> public DataSet Ds
>           {
>               get
>               {
>                   object temp = ViewState["Ds"];
>                   return temp == null ? null : temp as DataSet;
>               }
>               set
>               {
>                   ViewState["Ds"] = value;
>               }
>           }
>
> ```
>     public void gridCustBind(int pageIndex)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             //open the db connection if it is closed...  
>             if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
>                 connection.Open();
>             command = new SqlCommand();
>             command.CommandText = "sp_Get_CustInfoSerach";
>             command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>             command.Connection = connection;
>             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", pageIndex);
>             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", int.Parse(ddlPaging.SelectedValue));
>             command.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
>             command.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
>
>             //SqlParameter outParam = command.Parameters.Add("@bal", SqlDbType.Float);
>             //outParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
>
>             command.Parameters.Add("@bal", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
>             command.Parameters["@bal"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
>
>             SqlDataAdapter daAcc = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
>
>             daAcc.Fill(Ds);
>            }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             lblMessageCustSerach.Text = ex.Message;
>             lblMessageCustSerach.Visible = true;
>         }  
>                 finally //Close db Connection if it is open....  
>         {
>             if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
>                 connection.Close();
>
>         }
>     }        
>
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (!IsPostBack == true)
>         {
>
>             gridCustBind(1);
>             if (gridCustomer.Rows.Count > 0)
>             {
>                 gridCustomer.DataSource = Ds;
>                 gridCustomer.DataBind();
>
>             }
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Mr Abbas In your code you have >> return temp == null ? null  . It means if temp is null then return null why ?

Comment: this is read property for dataset if dataset is null then return null otherwise return dataset value from viewstate

Comment: If you initialize it as null it would not be the good way

Comment: then how to initialize if its empty?

Comment: if it is the first run then you should init it with proper data, but if ViewState has it then load data from that.